# An App that counts the number of spoken words by using Speech Recognition

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Is there any way to count words in an audio file using some kind of (Offline) Speech Recognition? What would be the best approach to implement something like this?
And also is there any way to make it work continuous without having to restart it every time someone makes a pause while talking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer for my question for those who might need it:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        RecognitionListener {

    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO = 1;
    private TextView returnedText;
    private TextView returnedError;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView brojtextview;
    private SpeechRecognizer speech = null;
    private Intent recognizerIntent;
    private String LOG_TAG = "VoiceRecognitionActivity";
    private int ukupanbroj;

    private void resetSpeechRecognizer() {

        if(speech != null)
            speech.destroy();
        speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "isRecognitionAvailable: " + SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this));
        if(SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this))
            speech.setRecognitionListener(this);
        else
            finish();
    }

    private void setRecogniserIntent() {

        recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
//        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE,true);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
                "sr-RS");
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // UI initialisation
        returnedText = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        returnedError = findViewById(R.id.errorView1);
        progressBar =  findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        brojtextview=findViewById(R.id.brojtextview);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        // start speech recogniser
        resetSpeechRecognizer();

        // start progress bar
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

        // check for permission
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
            return;
        }

        setRecogniserIntent();
        speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull  int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied!", Toast
                        .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "resume");
        super.onResume();
        resetSpeechRecognizer();
        speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "pause");
        super.onPause();
        speech.stopListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "stop");
        super.onStop();
        if (speech != null) {
            speech.destroy();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBeginningOfSpeech");
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressBar.setMax(10);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onBufferReceived: " + buffer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEndOfSpeech");
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        speech.stopListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onResults");
        ArrayList<String> matches = results
                .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);


        String text = matches.get(0);
        returnedText.setText(text);

        String trimmed = text.trim();
        int words = trimmed.isEmpty() ? 0 : trimmed.split("\\s+").length;


        ukupanbroj+=words;
        brojtextview.setText( "" + ukupanbroj);




        speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int errorCode) {
        String errorMessage = getErrorText(errorCode);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "FAILED " + errorMessage);
        returnedError.setText(errorMessage);

        // rest voice recogniser
        resetSpeechRecognizer();
        speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onEvent");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPartialResults");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle arg0) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReadyForSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
        //Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRmsChanged: " + rmsdB);
        progressBar.setProgress((int) rmsdB);
    }

    public String getErrorText(int errorCode) {
        String message;
        switch (errorCode) {
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
                message = "Audio recording error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
                message = "Client side error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
                message = "Insufficient permissions";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
                message = "Network error";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
                message = "Network timeout";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
                message = "No match";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
                message = "RecognitionService busy";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
                message = "error from server";
                break;
            case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
                message = "No speech input";
                break;
            default:
                message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
                break;
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Android comes with an inbuilt feature speech to text through which you
>   can provide speech input to your app.

Here is a small sample code, on how you can use the inbuild API to recognize speech and convert it to text easily. After that, you can extract the text as a `String` and count the words in code, just as you would normally count words in a regular `String`, for example with `.split(" ")` or some other known method.

```
/**
 * Showing google speech input dialog
 * */
private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Receiving speech input
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
        }
        break;
    }

    }
}
```

(full original tutorial is here: https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/)